Nullable EmailAddress validation not working
I have two EmailAddress columns in my Debtor model:
[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Contact e-mailadres moet een geldig formaat zijn.")]
public string? ContactEmail { get; set; }

[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Factuur e-mailadres moet een geldig formaat zijn.")]
public string? InvoiceEmail { get; set; }

I get my Debtor from the SQL database with the following method:
Context = _dbContext.CreateDbContext();
_debtor = await Context.Debtors?.SingleOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id == DebtorId);

Within my database, the values of InvoiceEmail and ContactEmail are NULL - not "".
However, when I go to the edit page the columns within my Debtor are "" and not NULL. So when I hit save the validation throws an error "Email must be valid". Within my .net 7 project I used the same model without this issue.

Is something changed in .net 8? How to solve this issue?
I also tried it with the following model columns:
[DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = true, NullDisplayText = "[Null]")]
[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Contact e-mailadres moet een geldig formaat zijn.")]
public string? ContactEmail { get; set; }

[DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = true, NullDisplayText = "[Null]")]
[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Factuur e-mailadres moet een geldig formaat zijn.")]
public string? InvoiceEmail { get; set; }

Also did not solve the issue.

I am not sure what has changed but can you look into the DisplayFormatAttribute.ConvertEmptyStringToNull : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.convertemptystringtonull?view=net-8.0

@RahulSharma see my updated question. I tried that, did not solve the issue. Still the same result

Can you try using the RequiredAttribute.AllowEmptyStrings attribute and see if that works in your case: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute.allowemptystrings?view=net-8.0 @Jeremy

@RahulSharma AllowEmptyStrings is a property of the required attribute. My columns are not required. Adding [Required] is therefor not possible and would throw errors if I would add it.

RESOLVED: I found an issue within my database structure. Issue was not in my c# code
